# Javascript: Iterating over an array causes an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to iterate over some data in Javascript, using the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < fromdata.length; i++) {
    var mainid = fromdata[i].id;
    var sub = afcHelper_Submissions[mainid];
    /* do more stuff */
```

`fromdata` is an array of Objects that looks something like this:

```
[{ type="ffu", to=" Jon Corzine ", id=1, more...}, { type="ffu", to=" Jon Corzine ", id=2, more...}]
```

As you can see, I just want to get each object's id and store it to mainid and then do some more with it; however, I run into trouble: looping! Looping! Looping! The loop keeps running again and again. It never stops, and just manages to freeze up Firebug.

**Update**: Here's the "do more stuff", in all its pastebin glory: http://pastebin.com/Mfr90uq7. Note that I changed the variable name from sub to sub_m to avoid a potential conflict, but the problem persisted.

Comment: try to print the value of `i` and `fromdata.length` in the console and see what is happening

Comment: Are you sure you're not adding more elements to `fromdata` (and thus increasing `fromdata.length`)? Do you change `i` at any point by mistake?

Comment: then pretty much someting in `/* do more stuff */` is the problem. its good that you don´t post all the code you have, but you should neither post too little.

Comment: what is afcHelper_Submissions[] here ?

Comment: @luk2302 i've linked to the rest of the loop in my question, thanks!

Comment: @MotaChuha it's another array.

Comment: What can make your loop to infinity loop is the increasing of the `fromdata` array,

Comment: are you sure that is in an infinite loop as stepping inside the loop body all the time OR is the program just not stopping / coming to an end which would indicate that the error is somewhere else. Are you getting output from this line `console.log(sub_m.action)` endlessly often?

Comment: @luk2302 Yes, I get the output from `console.log(sub_m.action)` repeatedly (thousands upon thousands of lines) just bouncing back and forth between two members of `fromdata`; here's an example: http://pastebin.com/5xKxKJB5

Comment: how are the chances of recursion? Oh and try to rid the var keywords and magic might happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A loop only can be infinite if the condition is always true. In your case it looks that it should reach a false , but provably `formData` is getting new elements each iteration of the loop or `i` is being modified and returned to previous values.

What I recomend is to create variables that will be used only for comparasion purposes:

```
var max = fromdata.length;
for (var count = 0; count < max; count++) {
    var i = count;
    // your stuff using formdata and i
```

Now `max` and `count` will not be modified by the code in the loop and the loop will reach an end.